# .NET Core 3.1 OAUTH 2 Token Introspection with Custom JSON Response - "Status Code cannot be set because the response has already started"

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, identitymodel

I have already tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675102/asp-net-core-middleware-cannot-set-status-code-on-exception-because-response-ha), and nothing is working.

I am using package IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection v6.0.0.  The business use case I have is that I have to return a 401 Unauthorized status code *plus a custom JSON object in the response* when authentication fails.  This code works to return the JSON object, BUT it throws the same error on the backend each time, and once that starts happening, latency shoots up on my app.

Here's what I have so far:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddOAuth2Introspection(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = _idpAuthority;
        options.ClientId = _apiResourceName;
        options.ClientSecret = _apiResourceSecret;
    
        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
        {
            context.NoResult();
            if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(new ErrorListResponseModel().AddError("401", "UNAUTHORIZED")));     
            }
                               
        };
    });
```

This produces the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the
> response has already started.

The logging callsite of this error is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReportApplicationError`.

Whether I add or remove `context.NoResult()` -- no difference.

I've tried using a synchronous delegate function and returning `Task.CompletedTask` instead -- no difference.

If I don't explicitly set the `context.Response.StatusCode`, I get a `200` status code in the response, AND the error still throws!

The remarks in the library suggest that

> Invoked if exceptions are thrown during request processing. The exceptions will be re-thrown after this event unless suppressed.

. . . but I don't see any suggestions on how to suppress these exceptions.

Please help

Comment: have you tried changing the order of setting the status code, writing thebody and setting the content type? Can't cite any source, but I feel to remember that setting the status code should be last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by taking this code out of the `OnAuthenticationFailed` event and moving it into the `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` part of Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages((StatusCodeContext statusCodeContext) =>
{
    var context = statusCodeContext.HttpContext;
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = _applicationJsonMediaHeader;
        return context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(_serializedUnauthorizedError).AsTask();
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```